# Padding/Margin de bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Estoy aprendiendo a usar bootstrap haciendo una página basándome en un modelo y no consigo quitar el margen a la izquierda del botón de inicio. He probado muchas cosas cambiando el css (modificando margin, padding, etc) y no consigo cambiarlo aunque parezca una tontería :3

[image: Quitar el margen a la izaquierda de inicio]

Este es el código:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="miembros.html">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <section class="container-fluid">
        hola
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md-block visible-lg-block">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo/minilogo.jpg" title="logo" alt="logo" id="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola solo agrega style="padding-left: 0" a div.container para quitar el espacio.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 0;">
```

Saludos

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container" style="padding-left: 0;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="miembros.html">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <section class="container-fluid">
        hola
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md-block visible-lg-block">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo/minilogo.jpg" title="logo" alt="logo" id="logo">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```